# How to make a folded bath towel

Tags: modeling

What would be a good way of creating the shape of a realistic folded towel?

Would you use cloth simulation or just model it? 
I've no luck with either

[image: Reference]

Comment: I would go with making base mesh with modeling tools and then sculpt details.

Comment: In both seems possible to achieve good results. What is blocking you? Why are you stuck? Is it because of your modeling/simulation/artistic skills or because something in the software doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: "I've no luck with either" - pls elaborate what's the problem.

Comment: This is a really good tutorial to model an entire bathroom, at the 2:35:20 mark he shows how he did the towels. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXyRwS9lR6o&t=9781s

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the help I figured it out by:

Creating the outline by bezier spline

Created the with by using the depth setting in the curve meny

Converting it to a mesh and moved half of the geometry to create the with of the towel

Removed the edges on the other side

Used the solidify modifier to create the with of the towel on the other side

Fine tuned the geometry so the fold isn't resting in mid air

Used hair particles for the strands

[image]
[image]